# moveable but not editable rows in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

If I return false in `canEditRowAtIndexPath` because I want to forbid delete row when swiping to left, but meantime I want to let user to change order of rows. It seems not possible. `canMoveRowAtIndexPath` will not get called.

Any idea how to make rows moveable but not editable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

For cell to be movable:

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath         
{
    return YES;
}
```

For cell to be Non Deletable:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```